# Could not find method outputDir() on cucumber Java source of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber

I am not able to run the cucumber task for the "com.github.samueltbrown.cucumber" plugin.

I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/freid/app/build.gradle' line: 118

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'app'.
> Could not find method outputDir() for arguments [/Users/freid/app/src/cucumber/java] on cucumber Java source of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion='2.2.4.RELEASE'
        lombokVersion='1.18.4'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.psxpaul.execfork' version '0.1.8'
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.7.2"
    id "com.github.samueltbrown.cucumber" version "0.9"
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4'
}

sourceSets {
    cucumber {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/cucumber/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/cucumber/resources')
    }
}

cucumber {
    formats = ['html:build/reports/html', 'json:build/reports/cucumber.json']

    jvmOptions {
        environment 'tag', System.getProperty("tag")
        environment 'cucumber.local.server', 'localhost'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the plugin `com.github.samueltbrown.cucumber` version 0.9 was released in 2015 and you are trying to run with a recent Spring Boot version, I would assume you are using a recent Gradle version as well.

So I believe you are hitting an incompatibility between the plugin and the Gradle version. Most likely an API changed and what the plugin does internally no longer works.
`[/Users/freid/app/src/cucumber/java]` looks like the `toString` of a collection of files, while `SourceDirectorySet.outputDir` only accepts a single `File`. So my guess is that the API of what returns the value that is used changed from a single file to a file collection at some point.